# How to point ALB's hesos instead of rightscale?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, mesos, rightscale

our company is using Rightscale for cloud computing management and we are migrating applications from rightscale to mesos. I'm working on migrating a application and i'm new to Route53/DNS concepts. 
I have endpoints(url) for application and can some guide me through the process of routing those ALB's to Mesos instead of rightscale.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Load Balancer is a distributed system.  Instead, when you create an ELB, you are given a DNS name such as ExampleDomainELB-67854125.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. AWS gives a facility to set up a DNS CNAME entry pointing for e.g. www.exampledomain.com to the ELB-supplied DNS name.

In order to point your ALB to Route 53 follow the below steps:

1. Go to **Route 53** and select your Hosted Zone (Creat
2. Select '**Create a Record Set**'
3. Select the '**Type**' as **CNAME**
4. Set **Alias** to **Yes**
5. Set **Alias Target** to the **DNS name of your Application Load Balancer**
6. Click on '**Create**'.

In this way, you ALB will be pointing to Mesos Application